# appsettings.json value not showing up in deserialized object

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I have a json file with elements lined up this way:

```
{
     "Connection": 
      {
        "data": "...connection string..."
      }
     "Log":
     { 
       "stuff": " value"
     }
etc...
}
```

I have this model:

```
 public class Connection
    {
        public string data { get; set; }
    } 



   public class RootObject
    {
        public Connection Connection { get; set; }
    }
```

and attempt to populate this way:

```
   using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("appsettings.json"))
        {
            string json = r.ReadToEnd();
           var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);        
       }
```

The json string gets the entire file as expected but that specific value (data) does not populate - at least I can't access it.  data is null after the DeserializeObject line.

Do I need to refer to it more specifically? It's one of many values in that json file.

Comment: your object has a layer of indirection. You have a `Connection` property that has an object that you expect.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve].

Comment: The JSON may not be what you are showing us. Please run the code. After `json` is assigned please check its value in the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/string-visualizer-dialog-box?view=vs-2017 (please use that tool **specifically**). Then copy that value, and paste the entire value in your question.

Comment: It was a startup.cs issue as I noted below.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: You may wish to delete the question then. Also, next time, please check the value of `json` before posting the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your json data has one level above `Connection`, so you won't see it.

You need some wrapper class. `var myData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyData>(stringValue);`

```
public class MyData{
  public ConnectionClass Connection {get;set;}
}

public ConnectionClass{
  [JsonProperty("data")] // to keep code styling consistent
  public string Data {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: The DeserializeObject returns a null Connection class. Does something else need to be initialized?

Comment: post a complete sample pls, I'll help you troubleshoot

Comment: @John the whole json and all the classes you have. Or at least the json

Comment: Oh I found the solution!  I needed to configure that Connection section in the startup.cs.  

   services.Configure<Connection>(Configuration.GetSection("Connection"));

Comment: I assumed you still needed @StenPetrov's solution as well? If so, you may wish to upvote it John.